# Using XCode Instruments ObjectAlloc -- how to show only my classes?

Tags: xcode

In the Instruments tool, ObjectAlloc, is there a way for me to filter the classes it shows to just classes that I've created, and not system classes?

ie I don't want to see all the instances of CFArray and GSEvent but I want to see all the instances of MyClass, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. Sorry. I remember it used to be recommended that you prefix all your classes with the same start String - the way Apple still uses NS**** for it's classes (from NextStep).

I don't know if people still do this but it would enable you to filter ObjectAlloc's results somewhat in Instruments.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I will try that for now, thanks.